# Getting compilation error "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" at for loop in reducer

Tags: java, arrays, hadoop, mapreduce, iterator

Getting compilation error "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"  at for loop in reducer.

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> Output, Reporter arg3)
            throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int sum = 0;
         for (IntWritable val : values) {
           sum += val.get();
```

In above code, getting compilation error  "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" at `"for (IntWritable val : values)"`. How to use loop in the same?

Answer (score 2):

Either pass an `Iterable<IntWritable>` instead of `Iterator<IntWritable>` to the method, or use `hasNext()` and `next()` to iterate over the elements of the `Iterator` :

```
 while (values.hasNext()) {
    IntWritable val = values.next();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
    for (IntWritable val : (Iterable<IntWritable>)() -> values) {
        sum += val.get();
        ....
```

`(Iterable<IntWritable>)() -> values` is equivalent to

```
    new Iterable<IntWritable>() {

        @Override
        public Iterator<IntWritable> iterator() {
            return values;
        }

    };
```